# ui-select in ui-grid filterHeaderTemplate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-select

I am trying to use ui-select in header filter template, but can't make it work;

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vOdh7PSL4rIESQKJu4rn?p=preview)

Thanks!

```
   [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/vOdh7PSL4rIESQKJu4rn?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

Your plunker seems fine. Can't tell you where you are going wrong but it worked if I used templates rather than directive of yours.

```html
  <script type="myTemplate" id="uiSelectTemplate">
    <ui-select ng-model = "colFilter.term" append-to-body = "true" class="g-select">
      <ui-select match-placeholder="colFilter.placeholder">< /ui-select-match> < ui - select - choices repeat = "option.id as option.value for option in colFilter.options" >
      <div ng - bind = "option.value" > < /div></ui - select - choices > < /ui-select>
  </script>
```

And then use:

```
$templateCache.put('#cohortVersionToolBar')
```

to insert the template in to the grid.

You will have to inject $templateCache into your controller.
I have forked your plunkr. [Here it is](http://plnkr.co/edit/5el6oI20hne1JRgzE9lZ)

Comment: unfortunately what you've got is a simple text filter, not a ui-select dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Is there any a specific reason you are using ui-select? This can be done by creating a directive. check my plunkr...

```
[http://plnkr.co/edit/tXZYrfQFzLhred5i0UeG?p=preview][1]
```

- line 9-12: created my array of objects
- line 22-24: created filterHeaderTemplate by calling my custom  directive
- line 59-64: created directive